# Kneading Theory and ordering(Y)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, dynamical-systems

At the moment I am reading the book "An Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems" by Robert L. Devaney.

In Chapter 18, "Kneading Theory", he introduces following stuff.

**Definition** Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ be a $C^1([0,1])$ map. $f$ is unimodal if $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ and $f$ has a unique critical point $c \in (0,1)$.

Now let $f$ be a fixed unimodal map.

**Definition** Let $x \in [0,1]$. The itinerary of $x$ under $f$ is the infinite sequence $S(x)= (s_0,s_1,s_2,\dots)$ where $$s_j = \begin{cases} 0 \quad \text{if} \quad f^j(x) < c\\
1 \quad \text{if} \quad f^j(x) > c\\
C \quad \text{if} \quad f^j(x) = c.
\end{cases}$$ where $C$ is just some symbol.

We first define an order on $\{0,C,1\}$ by $0 < C$, $C < 1$ and $0 < 1$.

Then he defines an ordering on the space $\Sigma_C := \{(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}| x_n \in \{0,C,1\} \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

**Definition** We say $s,t \in \Sigma_C$ have discrepancy $n$ if $s_0 = t_0$, $s_1 = t_1$, $\dots$, $s_{n-1} = t_{n-1}$ and $s_n \neq t_n$.
Additionally $\tau_n(s) = \#\{s_i | i \in \{0,\dots, n\} \text{ and } s_i = 1 \}$.

**Definition** Let $s,t \in \Sigma_C$ and assume $s$ and $t$ have discrepancy $n$. We say $s \prec t$ if either ($\tau_{n-1}(s)$ is even and $s_n<t_n$) or ($\tau_{n-1}(s)$ is odd and $s_n>t_n$).

This ordering hat the property that for $x,y \in [0,1]$ holds

if $S(x) \prec S(y)$, the $x<y$.

if $x<y$, then $S(x) \preccurlyeq S(y)$.

But is there a deeper intuition behind, more than just this technical properties?

Comment: If I see this right, this reconstructs the usual order on $[0,1]$ from the index sequence $S(x)$. Of course, the map $S$ need not strictly conserve the order, there can be information loss in it, there can be intervals having the same itinerary, thus the equal sign in the last claim.

Comment: Yes, this is what these two properties tell. So it represents somehow the order of the real numbers in the space $\Sigma_C$. Does this tell us more about $\Sigma_C$?

Comment: It might help arguing about cycles. It looks close to the interval arguments like in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2547064/115115, as said there, keywords are "Sharkovsky's ordering" and "Period 3 implies chaos" by Li and Yorke, see http://euler.genepeer.com/period-three/